# Is it possibile to create an orphan branch and set a new remote repository only for this last branch?

Tags: git, github

I have an origin private repository and want to keep it private.
However I need to create a public version of my work and was thinking of creating an orphan branch.

Is it possible to set a new remote repository that track only this new orphan branch?

This could let me have a master repository that's tracked with a private remote repository, and then an orphan that is uploaded to a public remote repository.

Is this possible? 
I'm thinking something like this:

```sh
git checkout --orphan orphan_name
git rm -rf .

// some refactor and commits

git remote add public <some-other-github-repo>
git push -u public <orphan_name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new public repo and only push the one branch. 
    git remote add public 
    git push -u public my_branch
    git push public my_branch

The `git push -u` line will set the push repo for my_branch to the specific repo.

Comment: Note that the OP's post shows `git rm -rf .` (which won't delete the `.git` directory itself, vs plain `rm -rf .` which would).

Comment: Good catch. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, so I could do that with my orphan branch without the related history (from what I understand  `git rm -rf .` is for remove files from stage and history of the orphan branch, right?)

Comment: That is correct. Just out of curiosity why not just make a whole new repo? It seems like there is nothing related between the 2 branches.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon mm thinking about your last question, I think it's that I wanted to have one folder on my PC with the project. Even if that there's nothing related between the branches, the files inside the physical folder are the same. I'm still thinking if this does make sense by the way :D

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon oh, another and more important reason: what if I added some sensible content, like a password, in a past commit. Then even if I removed it, that content could still be there in the history of the repository. So I prefer to make a "tabula rasa" before publish any project as public.